# set position of player in Start()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2D rigidbody as my player. When the game starts, I want to set its position to (0,-3). I looked at the docs and figured I could use the following methods to achieve what I wanted:

```
rb.position = new Vector2(0.0f,-3.0f);
```

```
rb.position.Set(0.0f,-3.0f);
```

```
rb.transform.position = new Vector2(0.0f,-3.0f);
```

I put these in the Start() right after rb = this.GetComponent();However, none of these worked.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing else blocking the position update / resetting it later? Since `Start` is not yet relevant for the physics update I would go for `transform.position` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Rigidbodies shouldn't be moved by their position, rotation or the Translate variables/function, it can have bad effects since it's controlled by the Physics engine. If your Rigidbody is marked as Kinematic, your should use [Rigidbody2D.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) to move it.